# Automatically check a checkbox if a group of others are not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm a librarian working on improving my library's main search feature. I am trying to get a checkbox labeled "Everything" to check automatically if users deselect all of the other options ("books," "articles," "music," "videos".)

Here's the relevant javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $others = $('input[class="checkoption"]').not('#everythingbox')
  $others.change(function() {
    if (this.checked==false) {
      $('#everythingbox').prop('checked', true)
    }
  });
});
```

I almost have it working, but there's a problem: if I select two or more choices and deselect one, "Everything" checks automatically, but I only want it to check automatically if none of the others are checked.

Here is the full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kr0syfn3/11/

Comment: Unrelated to solving your problem - looking at the fiddle, you should probably consider moving all the code in similar event listeners into the same function. There is no reason to register multiple event listeners for each chunk of logic. For example, `$others.change...` is used 3 times when you can just merge the logic in the separate callbacks into one.

Comment: I posted a solution. Check if and see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Tag is JavaScript code is jquery. WOW 

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your help! I am still new to doing this kind of work, so I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your fiddle. You basically need to check all the other check boxes when a change happens and update the everything box accordingly.

Here's the updated fiddle [jsfiddle.net/john_lay/kr0syfn3/12/](https://jsfiddle.net/john_lay/kr0syfn3/12/)

Apologies in advance for commenting out some of your code, but there was a lot of repetition. Finally you should add your change events inside the `$(document).ready(function() {});` handler.

Comment: This is very useful and it works perfectly! I really appreciate your taking the time to help with this!

Comment: If user manually selects "everything" it should probably deselect the other checkboxes, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to inspect **all** checkboxes each time any one of them is clicked. Right now, you are just inspecting the one single one that is clicked. To inspect all of them, you will need to use a loop (I'm using the `each` function in my sample below), and you might have to change your logic just a bit because you are now inspecting all items:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $others = $('input[class="checkoption"]').not('#everythingbox');
    $others.change(function() {
      var othersToCheck = $('input[class="checkoption"]').not('#everythingbox');
      var anyChecked = false;
      $.each(othersToCheck, function(index) {
        if ($(this).checked) {
          anyChecked=true;
        }
      });
      $('#everythingbox').prop('checked', !anyChecked)
    });
});
```

Comment: Native JavaScript's `.every()` would be helpful here. The other thing you can do is simply check `$('input.checkoption:not(#everythingbox):checked').length`

Comment: Also, this code as it stands checks the everything checkbox when you select any other option, this is undesired functionality. `checked` is not a valid property on the jQuery wrapper. It should be `$(this).prop("checked")`. `$(this).checked` is returning undefined every time and so `anyChecked` is always false, so you are always checking the everything box.

Answer (score 0):

You could try selecting all the checkboxes that are selected and then comparing the lists, to see if all checkboxes have been selected? E.g.

```
var $others = $('input[class="checkoption"]').not('#everythingbox')

$others.change(function() {
    var $checked = $('input[class="checkoption"]:checked').not('#everythingbox')
    if ($checked.length != $others.length) { //not all the boxes are checked
        $('#everythingbox').prop('checked', true)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

The most concise answer to this would be to leverage the power of jQuery's built in selectors, like so:

You will also want to handle if the user selects the everything checkbox manually by clearing the rest of the selected checkboxes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inputs = $('input.checkoption');
  $inputs.on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") !== "everythingbox") {
      $('#everythingbox').prop('checked', !$('input.checkoption:not(#everythingbox):checked').length)
    } else {
      $inputs.not("#everythingbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1<input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" /> 2
<input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" /> 3
<input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" /> 4
<input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" /> everything
<input type="checkbox" class="checkoption" id="everythingbox" checked/>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var $others = $('input[class="checkoption"]').not('#everythingbox')
console.log($others)
$('#everythingbox').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $others.prop('checked', false)
        $('#everythingbox').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
$others.change(function () {
    var check = false;
    var l = $others.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if ($others[i].checked) {
            check = true;
        }
    }
    if (check) {
        $('#everythingbox').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#everythingbox').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('#everythingbox').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#everythingbox').prop('checked', true);
    }
})




var music1 = $("input[id='musiccheck']");
var music2 = $("input[id='musicscores']");

music1.on('change', function () {
    music2.prop('checked', this.checked);
});

music1.on('change', function () {
    music2.prop('unchecked', this.unchecked);
});

$(document).ready(function () {

});
```